# How django validates and saves inlineforms

Tags: python, django, validation

I would like to implement my own functionality similar to Django inlineformsets. What I'm interested in is how Django deals with validation and saving of a main object together with it's related objects in inline forms.

Let's say I have two models: `Blog` and `Entry`. `Entry` has a foreign key to the `Blog` that is not null. I want to be able to create both the blog and it's entries in one place. This is how I would do it using Django inline forms:

```
blogform = BlogForm(request.POST)
if blogform.is_valid():
    tmp = blogform.save(commit=False)
    entriesform = EntryInlineFormset(request.POST, instance=tmp)
    if entriesform.is_valid():
        entriesform.save()
        blog.save()
```

What's going under the hood here? How is Django able to validate entries without blog being saved to the database? I wanted to find this in Django code, but I wasn't able to find the place where they actually do this.

My gues is they create a transaction. They save the blogform and if the entriesform is invalid they rollback. However what if the entriesform is valid, what next? Does the blog instance stay saved? What if `save` never gets called then.

Or do they span the transaction over two methods (`is_valid` and `save`)? I don't think it's best practice to start the transaction in one method and end it in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate them both before calling save on either. You can pass a blank instance into both the parent form and the formset.

```
blog = Blog()
blogform = BlogForm(request.POST, instance=blog)
entriesform = EntryInlineFormset(request.POST, instance=blog)
blog_valid = BlogForm.is_valid()
entries_valid = entriesform.is_valid()

if blog_valid and entries_valid:
    ... save ...
```

I validate the forms separately and save the results to variables to avoid short-circuiting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Daniel. This helped a little, but I probably poorly explained myself. Do you happen to know how the implementation of django `BaseInlineFormset` is able to get the blog id (or any not null foreign key basically), if it needs it for validation to pass? I would like to know the internals so I could implement something similar in my app.

Comment: Can you give an example of where the FK is required for validation? "Django" doesn't do this in the formset at all: I expect you are referring to the behaviour in the admin, which is done in [ModelAdmin.changeform_view](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1355).

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is no validation of FK in the formset. It will raise an `IntegrityError` if you try to save it. `entriesform` just keeps the reference to the `blog` instance and after the `blogform` is saved the `entriesform`'s reference has the id and the formset can be saved. This is what I wanted to know, many thanks!